# change color of Arabic Diacritics in richtextbox C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project to diacritize the Arabic Texts and I need to show the Arabic Diacritics in different color in the richtextbox. I tried the following code but it does not work properly since it consider the diacritics as a part of the Arabic letter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Text.Length; i++)
{
    if (richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'َ' || richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'ً' || richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'ُ'|| richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'ٌ'|| richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'ِ'|| richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'ٍ'|| richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'ّ'|| richTextBox1.Text[i] == 'ْ')
    {
         richTextBox1.SelectionStart = i;
         richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
         richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use [string.Normalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eaxk1x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work